# SQL Procedure CREATE Table with variable Tablename

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

i need to create table with a variable name.

Heres my code, i dont know why it not work.

```
BEGIN
  SET @tablename = tablename;
  SET @sql_text = concat('CREATE TABLE ',@tablename,' (ID INT(11) NOT NULL, team0 DOUBLE NOT NULL, team1 DOUBLE NOT NULL)');

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

And here is the error:

> Procedure execution failed
>
> 1054 - Unknown column 'TestTableName' in 'field list'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap `tablename` with `'` to indicate that it is string literal and not identifier.

```
BEGIN
  SET @tablename = 'tablename';
  SET @sql_text = concat('CREATE TABLE ',@tablename,' (ID INT(11) NOT NULL, team0 DOUBLE NOT NULL, team1 DOUBLE NOT NULL)');

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/472ae/1/0)**</kbd>

And please read [CREATE TABLE @tbl](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Cre_tbl) because creating tables at runtime could indicate poor design.

Answer (score 2):

```
BEGIN
  SET @tablename = 'tablename';
  SET @sql_text = concat('CREATE TABLE ',@tablename,' (ID INT(11) NOT NULL, team0 DOUBLE NOT NULL, team1 DOUBLE NOT NULL)');

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the problem is the table name itself and the lack of quotes (as others have noted).  When writing this type of code, you might consider using `replace()` rather than `concat()`.  This allows you to do:

```
BEGIN
  SET @tablename = 'tablename';
  SET @sql_text = '
CREATE TABLE @tablename (
    ID INT(11) NOT NULL,
    team0 DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    team1 DOUBLE NOT NULL
)';

  REPLACE(@sql_text, '@tablename', @tablename);

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

I find that this approach is much easier to debug and maintain.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `SET @sql_text = REPLACE(@sql_text, '@tablename', @tablename);`? Without `SET` the original variable will be unaffected + you need to indicate that it is variable with `@` (typo probably).